# Как добавить пользовательское поле в списке свойств товаров в Битрикс24 (коробка)?

Tags: php, битрикс24

Всем доброго времени суток.
Есть раздел товаров сделки в её карточке.
[image: Товары в сделке]

Мне нужно добавить собственное поле типа "Привязка к сотруднику" в этот набор свойств:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу допереть как это реализовать. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

UPD: Добавил тестовое поле в грид этого шаблона (crm.entity.product.list). Теперь мне нужно подвязать в этот столбец поле привязки к сотруднику на каждую строчку. Если кто-то разбирается, просьба, помочь

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://helpdesk.bitrix24.ru/open/5488795/ и https://helpdesk.bitrix24.ru/open/5488473/

Comment: К сожалению, эти руководства не могут мне помочь. В первом случае добавляется поле лишь к сущности (сделке, лиду и т.д.). Во втором случае добавляется лишь поле товара, которое, во-первых, одно для всех (например, в одной сделке значение поля=1, а в другой сделке это поле этого же товара=2 - так не получится), а во-вторых, это свойство не появляется на странице свойств товаров сделки(